# Deleting dynamically created component?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

In the `OnCreate` event, I have code which adds menu items to a `std::vector` (for the purposes of this question, it could be buttons, or any other components we create dynamically with the `new` operator):

```
// Iterrate through styles and hints and construct menu
for (int i=0; i<styleNamesAndHints->Count; i++) {
    TMenuItem* miTheme = new TMenuItem(miRoot);
    miTheme->Caption = styleNamesAndHints->Strings[i].SubString(0, styleNamesAndHints->Strings[i].Pos(styleNamesAndHints_Delimeter)-1);
    miTheme->AutoCheck = false;
    miTheme->AutoHotkeys = maManual;
    miTheme->RadioItem = false;
    miTheme->GroupIndex = MENU_GROUP_INDEX_STYLES;

    miTheme->OnClick = &miStyles_Click;
    miTheme->OnDrawItem = &miStyles_DrawItem;
    miTheme->OnMeasureItem = &miStyles_MeasureItem;
    miTheme->ImageIndex = IL_MENU_A_THEME;
    miTheme->Tag = miStyleArray.size();

    miStyleArray.push_back(miTheme);

    miRoot->Add(miTheme);       
}
```

Then in the `OnDestroy` event, we clean up the vector `miStyleArray`:

```
// Clean up miStyleArray vector, delete each element
while(miStyleArray.empty()==false) {
    delete miStyleArray.back();
    miStyleArray.pop_back();
}
```

This code works... I have no errors, everything works perfectly....

Now, someone told me that code like this could lead to errors and that, I quote, I should not use operator `delete` on objects that have parent, parent of the object is responsible for destroying and clean up..

As a matter of fact, the person that told me this is a moderator at a C++Builder forum, and warned me that I could be banned next time for such code! Here is the [post link](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread2942359.html).

Who is right, who is wrong??

Comment: If your forum threatens to ban you just for posting perfectly legitimate code, then you should find a friendlier forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to manually `delete` a component instance that has an `Owner` or `Parent` assigned. The component's destructor will remove the instance from its `Owner`/`Parent`'s internal list so the instance is not freed a 2nd time.

On the other hand, a component instance with an `Owner` assigned does not need to be `delete`'d manually, it will be freed when its `Owner` is freed, so your `OnDestroy` code is redundant and can be removed.

---

On a side note: you *should NOT* use the Form's `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` events in C++Builder.  They are a Delphi idiom that *can* lead to *undefined behavior* in C++ if you are not careful.  `OnCreate` *can* fire before your Form's constructor, and `OnDestroy` *can* fire after your Form's destructor. As such, you should use the Form's actual constructor and destructor instead.